# Django 1.4: Why is my context processor not working?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-1.4

I recently upgraded a project from Django 1.3 to 1.4, and that seems to have broken my context processor.

In `myapp/myapp/processors.py`:

```
def currentPath(request):
    return {'current_path': request.get_full_path()}
```

In `myapp/myapp/settings.py`:

```
from django.conf import global_settings

global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += (
    'myapp.processors.currentPath',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)
```

In any template, `{{ current_path }}` is expected -- and did, until the upgrade, return the current path. Now, it is not getting processed at all. I'm absolutely stuck here.

Comment: Is myapp.processors.currentPath on python path? Do you get some kinds of errors?

Comment: I get no errors, it just fails silently.

Comment: Are DEBUG and TEMPLATE_DEBUG turned on?

Comment: I turned them on and it still behaves the same way.

Comment: @supervacuo importing all of the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS did it rather than inheriting from global_settings. I also moved the context processors into a different app. I've had other app structure issues since migrating to 1.4, this must be part of them.  If you make this an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for kicks, would you consider specifying that setting the usual way:

```
- global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += (
+ TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (                                                 
+     'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',                                   
+     'django.core.context_processors.debug',                                       
+     'django.core.context_processors.i18n',                                        
+     'django.core.context_processors.media',                                       
+     'django.core.context_processors.static',                                      
+     'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
     'myapp.processors.currentPath',
     'django.core.context_processors.request',
 )
```

This could eliminate your (useful-looking!) reference to `global_settings` as a source of the issue.

Secondly, if you run

```
manage.py shell
```

does

```
from myapp.processors import currentPath
```

work? Your project structure seems a litte quirky (I haven't seen a context processors in the same directory as `settings.py` before; my `context.py` is in the same directory as a `models.py`, which I understand should usually not be the same directory as `settings.py`).

*(Converted from comment to answer at OP's request)*

Answer (score 6):

In `Django 1.8` adding processors to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` won't work.

```
Deprecated since version 1.8:
Set the 'context_processors' option in the OPTIONS of a DjangoTemplates backend instead.
```

You have to do it like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            # insert your TEMPLATE_DIRS here
        ],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # Insert your TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS here or use this
                # list if you haven't customized them:
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
                'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'loaders': [
                # insert your TEMPLATE_LOADERS here
            ]
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Goddamn thank you!! I wish they would add a warning if you have the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` global in settings, I'm sure this will catch a lot of people out like myself following out of date online guides

Answer (score 2):

You should return dict:

```
def currentPath(request):
    return {'current_path': request.get_full_path()}
```

Comment: Please only return {'current_path': request.get_full_path()}, without parentheses

Comment: Ack... shoot, I am. I mistyped the question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the `RequestContext` for the context processors to be processed.

You can use the [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) shortcut to have it included automatically:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
   context = {}
   return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', context)
```

If you're using classed-based views, the `RequestContext` will be included automatically.

Comment: I am. Example view is:  `return render_to_response('template.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))`

Comment: If @Matthew weren't including `RequestContext`, it wouldn't have worked in Django 1.3 either.